# Trying to make a sorted list only have unique numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

Here is my code:

```
def lotteryNumbers(m,n):
    newList = []
    uniqueList = []
    n=n+1
    for i in range(1, n):
        if i <= n:
            randomness = int(random.randint(1,m))         
            newList.append(int(randomness))
    for number in newList:
        if number not in newList:
         uniqueList.append(number)
    sortNewList = uniqueList.sort()
    print(newList)
    print(uniqueList)
    return uniqueList
```

but nothing is showing in uniqueList with the second for loop added. taken out, I get a list for newList, but the numbers aren't distinct. I'm trying to do it without using a set and more of a if item not in newList then append to uniqueList and return a sorted (ascending) list with unique numbers.

Comment: What are `m` and `n`? Can you give some more info on what you are wanting?

Comment: Can you add the line calling the function?

Comment: m is the maximum the random number can be (starting at 1)

Comment: n is the amount of random numbers for the function

Comment: so (50,3) would return a list [(random#1-50),(random#1-50),(random#1-50)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to address some of OP's other questions since pellucidcoder's has provided a valid solution

Nothing shows up in uniqList because the second for loop:

1. Loops through all items in newList
2. Asks if the item is NOT in newList

Part 2 is never true because the item came from newList to start with so uniqList comes back empty. If you changed the order a little bit to:

Answer (score 1):

I would just do:

```
def lotteryNumbers(m,n):
    list = []
    counter = 0
    while (counter < n):
        r = int(random.randint(1,m))
        if (r not in list):
            list.append(r)
            counter+=1
    list.sort()
    return list
```

Or for a one-liner...

```
def lotteryNumbers(m,n):
    return random.sample(xrange(1, m), n)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

Comment: This is a much better solution. Sorry can't +1 because I've run out today

Answer (score 0):

your statement if number not in newList is dubious since the numbers are in the list.
So this is what I have done,just made a little change to your code. There are efficient ways to do this, which I think already has been posted

```
def lotteryNumbers(m,n):
    newList = []
    uniqueList = []
    n=n+1
    seen = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        if i <= n:
            randomness = int(random.randint(1,m))         
            newList.append(int(randomness))
    for number in newList:
        if number is not seen:
            uniqueList.append(number)
            seen = number
    sortNewList = uniqueList.sort()
    print(newList)
    print(uniqueList)
    return uniqueList
```

Comment: Thank you for the structure. It was really helpful for reviewing!